# Where can I request Google Apps Script code to be built?

Tags: google-apps-script

Where can I hire freelance Google Apps Script coders?

Comment: I'd offer my services but this is not the place to do so. You can post your request in the [Google Apps Script Community Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-apps-script-community).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bruce McPhersons site hosts a list of GAS developers that do work for hire. I'm not sure where the google plus group moved to but if you can figure that out, they should be able to point you in the right direction.

Keep in mind that at least for free accounts there are certain kinds of processing limits in GAS as well.

Comment: Google Plus Community is still [here](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769) at least for business accounts

Comment: [The Google Apps Script Community](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-apps-script-community) was a pretty easy place to pick up a freelancer